# Is it possible to write to a settings XML stored within a JAR at run time?

Tags: java, xml, jar, jaxb, runtime

I have a large number of user settings that I want to store within an XML file. If it is possible, I would like to keep that XML file within the JAR itself, but so far I have found nothing that permits me to do that (lots of searching on Google turned up nothing).

I plan to use JAXB to handle reading and writing the XML file but first I need to know if it's possible to write to the XML file within the JAR during run time.

So far `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` seems to be on target except it only returns an input stream to read from the file. Is it possible at all to write to a file stored as a resource within a JAR file at run time? To open that file for Output?

Comment: No, actually more precisely, not without more work then it's worth. Remember, Jar files are just zipped files and it's a complete pain in the back to add files to them and you may not be able to rename/delete a jar while it's running on some systems...

Answer (score 1):

The Java process will lock dependencies on the classpath. You won't be able to change your JAR because the OS will tell you that it is in use.

```
java -cp "your_jar.jar;your_jar2.jar" YourMainClass
```

Only way I can think of is to [load your JAR at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime), so you can change a second jar that would be part of your application.

I (kinda) understand why you are doing it, but don't do it. Keep configuration out of your JAR.